# Eliminate null key from hashmap which is present inside an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I am looking for an optimized solution to remove `null` keys from a `HashMap`. This HashMap is present inside an `ArrayList`. Please find the example below.

```
public class Car {
    String year;
    String model;
    Map<String,String> colors;
}

List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Sample of the colors map could be like this:

```
{
   red(1),
   blue(2),
   green(3),
   black(4),
   null(5)
}
```

I need a solution to iterate over the `listOfCars`, get the map of colors and remove the `null` key from that. Trying to see any other options in Java8 rather than using an Iterator.

Thanks!

Comment: yes.  car.getColors.remove(null);

Comment: What is difficult about this?  `for (Car car : listOfCars) { car.colors.remove(null); }`.

Comment: I was confused a bit with the multiple iterations. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What you really need is a solution that prevents the null from getting in there in the first place.

Comment: @EJP, I have a usecase where we use the Thrift API to serialize/deserialize objects to Database(Cassandra). Using this API requires that each time you make any changes to the model, you need to regenerate the java classes using their utility(.exe). In scenarios if we miss to regenerate the java classes, it ends up deserializing objects containing map with null keys. Thats where I had been looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering a map cannot contain duplicate keys, we can, therefore, say that each `Map` instance of a `Car` instance will only ever have at most one entry with a `null` key.

The solution using the Java-8 `forEach` construct is:

```
listOfCars.forEach(e -> e.getColors().remove(null));
```

Although it can be done with a `for` loop or an enhanced `for` loop as well.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `Map.remove` directly, which avoids iterating over the entire map?

Comment: @LouisWasserman true, guess I overlooked the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks! I was also checking to see how I could remove the additional iteration. The answer had been quite straight forward. Should have checked again before posting it.

Comment: Iterating over a map can have a point if you don't know whether the map supports `null`, i.e. `remove(null)` and `containsKey(null)` could both throw. But then `map.keySet().removeIf(Objects::isNull)` still is simpler than operating with `entrySet()`.